# Find closed sequences of $y= \lceil log_2 x\rceil$ function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, discrete-logarithms

Question regarding the ceiling of a binary logaritm and it's sequences.

How to calculate the sequences of the closed form: $y= \lceil log_2 x\rceil$ where $x\in\mathbb{N} ?$

**Description**

I want to calculate the sequence (every $x$) from any arbitrary $y$. I was thinking maybe finding $x$ would be impossible because of ceiling removing the decimal part, but after some study I think otherwise.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x&log_2x&\lceil log_2x\rceil\\ \hline
1
&0&0\\ \hline
2
&1&1\\ \hline
3
&1.58...&2\\ \hline
4
&2&2\\ \hline
5
&2.32...&3\\ \hline
..
&...&...\\ \hline
\end{array}

For

- $y=2$, that is when $2 = log_2 x$ there are two elements (3,4) in the sequence. So $x$ can be 3 or 4.
- $y=3$, that is when $3 = log_2 x$ there are four elements (5,6,7,8) in that sequence, and so on...

So for $y=2$ and $y=3$ the sequences are finite. We would know the number of elements by $2^{y-1}$ if I am not mistaken. So by that we can compute every element in the sequence of an arbitrary $y$?

**Infinite or finite?**

A question that is not particular relevant to my original post, but would be kinda fun to know:
When $y=\infty$ the number of elements is $2^{\infty-1}$. Does it mean that $x$ is infinite and the number of elements in the $\lceil log_2 x\rceil$-sequence are infinite too?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to calculate
$$\sum_{k=2}^n \lceil \log_2(k)\rceil\text{?}$$

Comment: Not really. Bah, I used the wrong terminology. I am out after sequences, sorry. [edit: I changed series to sequences]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, for a given integer $y$, you want the set of integers $x$ such that
$$
\left\lceil \frac{\log x}{\log 2} \right\rceil = y.
$$
This equation is true exactly when
$$
y-1 < \frac{\log x}{\log 2} \le y
$$
which yields
$$
2^{y-1} < x \le 2^y
$$
so your set of $x$ values is $\{2^{y-1}+1,2^{y-1}+2,\dots,2^y\}$.